# Error while download Robolectric dependencies

Tags: android, robolectric, gradle-dependencies

I'm getting some error by trying to use Robolectric in my company.

I have configured the proxy, but I don't get to download Robolectric dependencies:

> Downloading:
>   org/robolectric/android-all/5.0.0_r2-robolectric-1/android-all-5.0.0_r2-robolectric-1.pom from repository sonatype at
>   https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/
>   [WARNING] Unable to
>   get resource 'org.robolectric:android-all:pom:5.0.0_r2-robolectric-1'
>   from repository sonatype
>   (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/): Error transferring
>   file: Connection timed out: connectError transferring file: Connection
>   timed out: connect . .

Comment: Did you find a fix for this?

Comment: I'm also facing this issue.